# error: cannot find symbol DaoSession and DaoMaster

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, android-databinding

I am using GreenDao in my application. Proguard is enabled for debug build.

After adding Data binding support, following issue arrived:

> /app/src/main/java/com/example/MainApplication.java:29:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> private DaoSession mDaoSession;
>
> ```
>       ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   class DaoSession
>   location: class Main Application

Same issue is coming for `DaoMaster`.

Also, this issue is coming:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
```

app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//For green dao
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ...
}
android {
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
    ...
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    kapt { generateStubs = true }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.8.3'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    dependencies {
        classpath  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @CodingTT Yes, I removed use of KAPT from the project. Though it is workaround and not a fix.

Answer (score 9):

Change you app build.gradle like this:

```
//For green dao
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Move your `greendao` plugin before the `kotlin` plugin.

Comment: You made my day !

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this can happen if code generation fails. It does not mean that the error is caused by GreenDao. Since you mentioned that you just introduced data binding it might be a problem with data binding.

The challenge is to find the actual error log, try to build with gradle with `--debug` and `--stacktrace` options and inspect the output.